# How to get OS X to set initial location of NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, location, frame, nswindow

How do I get OS X to place NSWindows in a reasonable default tiled-like location?  Like when I open TextEdit and create 10 documents, I see all the windows as having the same size, but somebody is smart enough to place them offset from each other a bit.  I'm sure that the app isn't doing this itself in code.

(I need a code-based, not NIB/XIB solution).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`-[NSWindowController setShouldCascadeWindows: YES]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/setShouldCascadeWindows:) for your window's window controller.